# Ajuda com Regex no VB.Net

Tags: regex, vb.net

Estou tentando montar uma expressão para executar no VB.Net que encontre no conteúdo de um arquivo o texto `GO`. O texto está sempre em uma nova linha e pode ou não conter espaços ou tabulação. 
Cheguei na expressão `GO|\t\s\n` mas ela identifica a palavra em qualquer parte do texto...

Um conteúdo de exemplo seria:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO  
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO       
--Não deve pegar o GO aqui ou no final do texto mesmo que essa linha termine com GO 
--Mas deve encontrar nas linhas 2 e 4 acima e na abaixo.
GO
```

Agradeço antecipadamente pela ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta `^GO\b`.

O `^` é pra pegar no começo da linha e o `\b` pra limitar a essa palavra.

Testa [aqui](https://regex101.com/r/1DTE9L/1).

Comment: Perfeito!! Obrigado @Anderson Pimentel